# Is it possible to find which expression evaluated true in the following if condition and on that basis I can find the value of a

Tags: java, if-statement

Is it possible to  find which expression evaluated true in the following if condition and on that basis I can  find the value of a.

```
import java.util.*;


 class a {





    public static void main(String args[]){

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int a=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
            if((i==a)||((i+100)==a)||((i+200)==a)||((i+300)==a)||((i+400)==a)||((i+500)==a)||((i+600)==a)||((i+700)==a)||((i+800)==a)||((i+900)==a)){
                //code 
                System.out.println("? condition is evaluated true");
            }

        }
     }
}
//I don't want to take more than one if statement.
```

Comment: Is evaluating them in seperate if statements out of the question? If so why?

Comment: Or refactor the statement and use `switch`.

Comment: @RichardTingle  my curiosity !!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular case the expression (a-i)/100 will give you the index of the condition which was true.

Comment: nice logical answer, like it!

Comment: the if statement can be changed to be if(a-i<1000 && !(a-i)%100)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use another for loop:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<1000; j+=100)
            if (i + j == a)
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(j / 100) + " condition is evaluated true");
}
```